# Divergence free vector field on spheres

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Let $S^{n-1}$ be the unitary sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $Y\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a zero-homogeneous vector field, that is
$$
Y(x)=Y\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right)\quad\mbox{in }\mathbb{R}^n,
$$
and consider the decomposition
$$
Y=\left(Y\cdot \frac{x}{|x|}\right)\frac{x}{|x|} + Y_T,
$$
where $Y_T$ is the tangential component of $Y$ to $S^{n-1}$. Now, suppose that
$$
\mathrm{div}_{S^{n-1}}(Y_T)=0 \quad\mbox{in }S^{n-1}
$$
where $\mathrm{div}_{S^{n-1}}$ is the tangential divergence on $S^{n-1}$: can we say that $Y_T=\nabla_{S^{n-1}}f$ for some function $f\colon S^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}$ or more information like $Y_T\equiv 0$ or for the radial component $(Y\cdot x/|x|)x/|x|$? Probably this is a trivial question, but I cannot find a simple reference. Moreover, if this is true, is it possible to lighten the regularity assumptions on $Y$?

Comment: If you think in terms of differential forms, zero divergence gives you a closed $(n-2)$-form on $S^{n-1}$; if $n\ge 3$, it will be exact, i.e., of the form $d\eta$ for some $(n-3)$-form. But only when $n=3$ will $\eta$ be a function.

Comment: I thought that the vector field $Y_T$ may be written, in terms of differential forms, as a $1$-form on $S^{n-1}$ for every $n\geq 3$. Can you explain better why do you see the vector field as $(n-2)$-form?

Comment: To define divergence of a vector field $X$, the easiest construction is to contract the volume form of your Riemannian manifold (here the sphere) against $X$ and differentiate. $\text{div}(X)\,dV = d(\iota_XdV)$. $\iota_XdV$ is the $(n-2)$-form to which I referred.